# RewriteEngine on gives error 403

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Index file exists and works.
When I create .htaccess file with the ONLY line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Any page on server gives me:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 403 mysite.com Wed Oct 5 22:25:25 2011 Apache/2.2.3
>   (Linux/SUSE)

Some server info:

> Loaded Modules    core prefork http_core mod_so mod_actions
>   mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_host
>   mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_default mod_authz_user mod_authn_dbm
>   mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_expires mod_include
>   mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_setenvif mod_ssl
>   mod_suexec mod_userdir **mod_rewrite** mod_php5

Apache version:

> SERVER_SOFTWARE   Apache/2.2.3 (Linux/SUSE)

Also did this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

In Directory section of httpd.conf

Log says just fact of error, not reasons:

```
89.112.xx.x - - [05/Oct/2011:22:32:34 +0200] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 403 1040 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
::1 - - [05/Oct/2011:22:32:45 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1 "-" "Apache/2.2.3 (Linux/SUSE) (internal dummy connection)"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please check below link. It will help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621643/turning-rewriteengine-on-creates-403-error-how-to-turn-on-followsymlinks#answer-22623427

Answer (score 45):

Place

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

as the first line of your .htaccess file. That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: `+FollowSymLinks` is required for the rewrite engine. If you look in Per-directory Rewrites on [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you will see this. Alternatively `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` can be used, although I think all of this depends on your apache configuration, with respect to performance and security.

Comment: Worked like a charm... Would be grateful if you could also explain why.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is that your main conf file has the permissions restricted. Do you have a line like:

```
<Directory /> 
    AllowOverride None 
</Directory>
```

in your main conf file? This will stop you from being able to change basically anything using a .htaccess file.

You can find out more about [apache permissions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html) on their website.

Comment: Yes, there was line "AllowOverride None", I've removed it, restarted apache, but it still gives me 403. Here's the current Directory section:

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    (Here was AllowOverride None)
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

Comment: Instead of removing the AllowOverride line change it to ALL or an appropriate subset of the functionality you want. There's more info on those options at the [apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Also, you want to make sure that you don't have another Directory declaration that limits the Override permissions somewhere in your conf files and that the mod_rewrite extension is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Check in the httpd.conf for the block of code. By default on a mac it's pretty restrictive. If it's only local and you don't care to much you can open it up like:

```
<Directory />
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

That might help, or, could be the file permissions themselves. The /var/log/apache2/error_log and /var/log/apache2/access_log may also give you a bit more detail as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Tarun's answer, `Options All` did the job for me :

```
<Directory "/path/to/apache/root"/>
    Options All
    ...
</Directory>
```